# How to use deleteFile() with argument that contains path separator?

Tags: android, file

In the application there is a `deleteFile(String path)` method implemented which has to delete the file located at the given path.

If the path contains path separator (character `/`), the method throws an exception, but to delete a specific file a full path has to be used and it contains a separator sign. Due to conflicting conditions I haven't found a way to successfully delete the file.

Does anyone know how to bypass the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what the exception is it is hard to say.  In general it is best to avoid hardcoding path separators and instead use the `File.separator` symbol.

How are you going about deleting the File?  The File class has a delete method; is that what you are using?

I'm guessing the problem might actually be unrelated to the things I mentioned up top, and instead be due to permissions.  Are you trying to access files or directories that your program has no right to access?

Answer (score -1):

According to javadoc of Application.deleteFile path couldn't contain path separator which is `:` at Unix and `;` at Windows, so at least according to java doc you can delete file with a full path.
Edit:
'\' is File.separtor not pathSeparator.